# Include Cython module in a Python package setup

Tags: python, package, cython, setuptools

I have a python package that includes a Cython part (see below a simplified version of the directory). But when I build my package, I cannot import the cython module. From what I could gather, I need some additional setup in my package but I can't figure it out.

```
package_name
    utils
        cython_module.c
    main.py
```

I have found some documentation [here](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#distributing-cython-modules) to do it with a `setup.py` file (see below). However, I am using a `setup.cfg` file to build the package. Is there a way to do the same thing with a cfg file or I need to have a `setup.py`?

```py
from setuptools import Extension, setup

setup(
    ext_modules = [Extension("example", ["example.c"])]
)
```